# Terminal Server trying to connect to 1433/tcp on client

Tags: sql, rdp, terminal

We are facing a strange issue here. Everytime a user connects via RDP client to one of our terminal server, the server itself tries to establish a connection via 1433/tcp to the client (and even 80/tcp sometimes).

Any ideas what could explain that?

Comment: Does `netstat -b` tell you which process on the server is trying to make the outbound connection to the client?

Comment: Are you saying that the server is initiating a new connection to the client or are you saying that the client initiated connection is initiated from port 1433 or port 80 on the client?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a custom port defined on the client http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759 like here 1433 is MSSQL default port .Please go with netstat -b over to the server and if it is possible on the client side also (as some remote desktop programs can be forced to try a different remote port )